# Automatic basket cleaning and quantity update - Mongoose, Mongodb, Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

when the user adds products to the cart, I decrease the quantity of product from the database. And after half an hour, I want the system to check the cart agai nand automatically restore the quantity also delete the product from the cart.

The code I wrote does this process, but how can I make it healthier? What are your suggestions? Which method should I use?

[The part where the basket is kept in the database and the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN1Ye.png)

```js
var task = cron.schedule('30 * * * *', async () => { // 30 minutes
            try{
                var userid = await req.user._id;
                var user = await User.findById(userid); //I find the user
                var items = user.cart.items;  //I find the user's cart
                var product_id = await Product.find({}, '_id'); // I called all the products

                if(items.length){ //If there is a product in the user's cart, come in
                    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){ 
                        for(var j=0; j<product_id.length; j++){
                            
                            var item = items[i]; //I find first product and second and... in the cart
                            var result = items[i].quantity; // I find its quantity

                            if(item.productId.toString() == product_id[j]._id.toString()){
                                var product = await Product.findById(item.productId).exec();
                                var productQuantity = product.productQuantity; // Find product quantity
                                var productQuantityResult = productQuantity + Number(result); // and restore stock

                                product.productQuantity = productQuantityResult; 

                                await product.save(); //Save the new quantity
                                await req.user.deleteCartItem(product_id[j]._id ); //delete the product from the cart
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }    
                }else{ // If there is a no product in the cart, come in
                    console.log("cart is empty!");
                    task.stop(); // stop the loop
                }
            }
            catch(err){
                next(err);
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you decreasing quantity from database when user adds them to cart in this way suppose a product has 2 quantity and user added them to cart and never bought but after 10 minutes a user came to your App and he really want to buy that product but he can't because the product is unavailable at App but available at store. So to overcome this problem you should handle it at client side that a user should not able to add more than available quantities, when user press save button to save in cart then add that record in database and when user goes to the payment page then you should check if available quantities are sufficient to fulfil the user's cart requirements if yes then grab the payment after successful transaction decrease the product quantity from real record of product.

Comment: Yes, what you said makes perfect sense. Thanks for the advice, I'll try that.